# Javascript is ruining my "grid"-function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

When I add my external Javascript-file , the "grid" function does not show as grid any more. But when I remove the JS, the grid-function comes back. How come?

I Tried to remove the Javascript.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Select all div elements with the class 'time-div'
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

  // Convert the NodeList to an array for easier manipulation
  const divArray = Array.from(divs);

  // Sort the array based on the data-time attribute
  divArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    const timeA = new Date(a.getAttribute('data-time'));
    const timeB = new Date(b.getAttribute('data-time'));
    return timeA - timeB;
  });

  // Clear the existing order of divs
  divs.forEach(div => div.remove());

  // Append the divs in the new order
  divArray.forEach(div => document.body.appendChild(div));
});
```

```html
<!--<nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>-->
<div class="grid">
  <div class="container" data-time="2023-11-19 12:00">
    <img src="bilder/fjell.png" alt="" />
    <h3>Bilde 1</h3>
    <h2>Tekst 1</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-time="2023-11-19 12:01 ">
    <img src="bilder/fjell.png" alt="" />
    <h3>Bilde 2</h3>
    <h2>Tekst 2</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-time="2023-11-19 10:02">
    <img src="bilder/fjell.png" alt="" />
    <h3>Bilde 3</h3>
    <h2>Tekst 3</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-time="2023-11-19 12:03">
    <img src="bilder/fjell.png" alt="" />
    <h3>Bilde 4</h3>
    <h2>Tekst 4</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS to show the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appends the sorted elements to the `<body>`, not the "grid" `<div>`. Get a reference to the grid container and add the elements to that:

```
// Append the divs in the new order
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
divArray.forEach(div => grid.appendChild(div));
```

Comment: Thank you, Pointy! It solved my problem! I really appreciate it! Thank you 